# Set same height and responsiveness for div only css

Tags: html, css, height, responsiveness

I have two divs and they should be the same size. I tried to put a height it works in desktop size but when I use different platform it become a mess

```
 ____________
|  ___________                 
| |         | |
| |         | |  
| |         | |
|_|_________  |
  |___________|
```

```css
.custombox {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.customparentbox {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="customparentbox">
  <div class="custombox">
    <p>Sample text</p>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes in your css

**From**

```
.custombox{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;}
  .customparentbox{background:red}
```

**To**

```
.custombox {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.customparentbox {
  width:100px;
  background: red;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cybs5090/) I made.

Comment: it's works but it's not responsive, the problem is the height , it should be the height of customeparentbox depends on the  height of custombox; and the custombox is auto and depends on the information of it inside

Comment: I edited the html with many text in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cybs5090/1/) and its working.

Comment: I know the problem, the problem is not your code, but the code in the shopify, thanks

Comment: @JonnyDOe I'm glad i was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjdkrgov/).

You have to add height and width to your parent div element and also to the child div. I have added `box-sizing` in the style so that it will render the actual width and height of the element.

Add `position:relative` to the parent element.

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.customparentbox{
background: red;
position: relative;
height: 80px;
width: 100px;
}
.custombox{
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
height: 80px;
width: 100px;
background: #fff; }
```

```html
 <div class="customparentbox">
  <div class="custombox">
     <p>Sample text</p>
     <button>test</button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: it's works but it's not responsive, the problem is the height , it should be the height of customeparentbox depends on the  height of custombox; and the custombox is auto and depends on the information of it inside

Comment: so you want the height of the parent customeparentbox should be the same height with the custombox child? then it depends with the content inside of it? am I right?